# Can one use android's location service without a google-/playstore account?

Tags: android

Can one use android's location service (i.e. Maps location) without an installed google account for the play services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. The basic location services are separate from Google Play Services. If you want to use the Map APIs or the new location APIs Google is including in Google Play Services, you will need to of course be using their SDK.